# Cache dependencies Not working with later version of Tomcat 9.0.37 version, the same is working in 9.0.20

Tags: java, spring

during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'taxLotsController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'taxLotsService'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'taxLotsServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
> introspect Class [com.frk.fds.api.service.impl.TaxLotsServiceImpl]
> from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

Please check your dependency on pom.xml maybe some dependency problem occurs:

you can try with this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.37</version>
    </dependency>
```

Maybe your `TaxLotsServiceImpl` class referring to another class i.e. is missing right now.
Please find out these missing dependencies if there are any.

Comment: you can see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader.html)

Comment: I see nothing related directly to Tomcat - why do you think it is a catalina dependency issue?

Comment: The exception is about `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`  and in one of the servlet projects I have the same error it was resolved when I change the dependency of the tomcat server version.